# Initialize a UIViewController before an item in a search bar is selected

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

I have a UITabBarController and a SearchBar on the home page.  The SearchBar searches items in the database and when an item is selected, jumps to that item in tab 2.  I changed my view hierarchy to use a UINavigationController in that tab.  In my viewDidLoad of the rootViewController for the UINavigationController, I push the first viewController (out of 3).  It's on this viewController that the search item goes to.

If I go to that tab just once, then my first viewController is loaded, and I select a search item, then it works.  The problem is if I never go to that tab and my first viewController is not pushed onto the stack, then the search does not know where to go and crashes.  I'm pretty sure I do **NOT** call viewDidLoad myself from my first tab to ensure that the first ViewController is pushed onto the stack.  How do I get around this problem?  Is there something I can do in loadView?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, `viewDidLoad` is a delegate method, not supposed to be called by you. One of the approaches that you can follow is- from tab 1, set an instance variable of `firstViewController` in tab 2, something like `pendingItemIndex`, corresponding to the item that is to be displayed in tab 2.

Then, in `viewDidLoad` of `firstViewController`, check if `pendingItemIndex` has a valid value (you can set the default value to -1). If it does, display the corresponding item.